# Input field auto-suggestion still shows after value doesnt match: Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am unable to turn off auto suggestions if the input field value doesn't match the pulled 'suggestions' anymore. I am getting data from a json file.

**Example**, 'Piranha' is a valid entry in the json file, so if i start typing P.I.R... it correctly shows 'Piranha' as a suggestion. But it keeps showing it even if I go beyond the letters and type something like 'Piranhat' (image attached for reference).

**Code:**

```
const specieInput = document.querySelector('#specie_input');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

const searchSpecies = async searchText => {
    let my_data = networkJSON.full_data;
    
    let matches = my_data.filter(my_data => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return my_data.specie.match(regex);
    });

    if (searchText.length === 0){
        matches = [];
        suggestions.innerHTML = '';
    }
    
    outputHTML(matches);
};

//Show results in HTML
const outputHTML = matches => {
    if(matches.length > 0) {
        const html = matches.map(match => `
            <div class="card card-body">
                <h4>${match.specie} - ${match.rate}</h4>
            </div>
        `
        ).join('');

        suggestions.innerHTML = html;
    }
}

specieInput.addEventListener('input', () => searchSpecies(specieInput.value));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are not resetting the html when 0 matches found.

```
if (matches.length === 0) {
    suggestions.innerHTML = '';
}
```

or you can also try to reset it at the first line of searchSpecies method